# Shiny issue : plotOutput a ggplot for each tab using do.call and loops

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I can't figure how should be written the inside of plotOutput() function to correctly render my graphs

In the server, by using the following function, I created 86 ggplot graphs which are in "output"
They are all named like  output$plot_14021 , i also later use graph_14021 while trying to make the plotOutput works.

```
for (i in unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)){
        rejets_temp<- donnees_rejets_cotiers %>% filter(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes==i 
                                                        & donnees_rejets_cotiers$`Paramètre : Code`==1449)
        DT <- data.table(year = factor(year(rejets_temp$`Date prélèvement`)),
                         valeur = rejets_temp$Résultat)
        DT_long <- DT %>% melt(id.vars = "year")
        tmp<-ggplot(DT_long, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
            scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') +
            geom_boxplot(color="blue",fill="royalblue" ,alpha=0.3) +
            geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "blue", linewidth=1) +  
            geom_hline(yintercept=100, linetype="dashed", color = "green", linewidth=1) +
            geom_hline(yintercept=1000, linetype="dashed", color = "darkorange", linewidth=1)+
            geom_hline(yintercept=10000, linetype="dashed", color = "red", linewidth=1)
        
        output[[paste0("plot_",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[i])]] <- renderPlot(tmp)
        #assign(paste0("graph_",i),tmp)
    }
```

The goal in the ui is to render the plot associated to the town (commune) in the associate tabItem

```
dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName="dashboard",
                    
                    fluidPage(
                        box(h2("Carte des Communes du littoral Normand"),width=12),
                        fluidRow(box(leafletOutput("Map_main"),width=8),box(h3("NYI"),width=4))
                                ))),
            do.call(tabItems,c(
                    list(tabItem(tabName="fcommunes")),
                    lapply(1:length(id_fiches),function(x){tabItem(tabName=id_fiches[x],
                                                                   fluidPage(
                                                                       box(h2("WIP Test fiche - ",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[x]),width=12),
                                                                       fluidRow(box(plotOutput(paste0("graph_",x)))
                                                                       ))) #eval(parse(text=paste0("output$plot_",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[x])))
                                                                   }) #output[[paste0("plot_",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[x])]]
                               )
                    )
                )
```

I've tried some sentences like the following ones in the renderOutput(), or just stopped using the output dataframe (as i understand it to be one) to store the ggplots

```
paste0("graph_14021")

paste0("output$plot_",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[x])
```

just to try with this one to render the graph but unsuccessfully.
also with my theoric expression of the name of each graphs and by using eval() and parse() while trying to "craft" the name of my graphs in the renderOutput()

```
(x is the equivalent in the ui of i (which originate from the serveur's loop))
paste0("plot_",unique(donnees_rejets_cotiers$id_communes)[x])
paste0("graph_",x)
```

the results range from "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'" in the beginning to no error messages

Answer (score 0):

you can set the tabs and add the plots (and other UI content) dynamically by `appendTab`'ing to the parent `tabPanel`'s id:

```
## taking the example iris dataset and setting one tab per species:

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id = 'commune_tabs',  type = "tabs")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
library(ggplot2)
selected_species <- reactive(input$commune_tabs)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)){
    appendTab(inputId = 'commune_tabs',
              tabPanel(i,
                       h1(paste('Species: ', i)),
                       renderPlot(
                           iris |>
                           ## note the parentheses after selected_species
                           filter(Species == selected_species()) |>
                           ggplot() +
                           geom_point(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
                           ## note that you can set several offsets and colors
                           ## in one run:
                           geom_hline(yintercept = rnorm(3),
                                      col = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
                                      )
                       )
                       
    ))
    }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]